# Tossing a coin until head shows up, how define probability function from the fact that $P(H)=p$?

Tags: probability

I am self studying Casella and Bergers Statistical Inference 2nd edition. In example 1.5.4 the following example is given:

> Suppose we do an experiment that consists of tossing a coin until a
> head appears. Let $p=$ probability of a head on any given toss, and
> define a random variable $X = $ number of tosses required to get a
> head. Then, for any $x=1,2,...,$
>
> $P_X(X = x) = (1-p)^{x-1}p,$
>
> since we must get $x-1$ tails followed by a head for the event to
> occur and all trials are independent...

Inuitively it makes perfect sense, but I don't understand how to reconcile the justification given for the definition of $P_X$ with the sample space of the experiment. Specifically I am unsure how to define the probability function used to define $P_X$.
I understand the example as follows:

The sample space $S = \{H, TH, TTH, TTTH, ...\}$, where $H=$"Head shows up", $T=$"Tail shows up"

The sigma algebra $B$ I am a bit unsure how to define, but I have come to the conclusion (and read elsewhere) that it should simply be the power set of $S$. In particular it does not contain the event $\{T\}$.

According to the definition of induced probability function given in the book, there is a probability function $P$ defined on $B$ that is used to define the induced probability function $P_X$ as $P_X(X=x) = P(\{s_j \in S: X(s_j) = x \})$  (The authors use the notation $P(X=x_i)$ for $P_X(X=x_i)$ but have stated earlier that it is just convenient notation).

The justification given by the authors for the definition of $P_X$ makes it sound like we are using the fact that "heads show up" and "tails show up" are independent events together with the probability function $P_2$ associated with the sample space $S_2 = \{H, T\}$ and sigma algebra $B_2 = \{S_2, \emptyset, \{ H\}, \{ T\} \}$, because the probability of
"$x-1$ tails" seems to refer to $P_2(\{T\})$  ( $\{T\} \notin B$ so it should not be referring to $P$ ).

But formally I think we ought to give the definition of $P_X$ in terms of $P$? I am thinking that from the fact that "$p=$ probability of a head on any given toss" we can conclude that $P(\{H\}) = p$. But I don't think we can conclude that the probability of a tail on any given toss is $1-p$ because the event $\{T\}$ is not in the domain $B$ of $P$. My question then becomes how do we define $P$ if the only thing we know is $S$, $B$ and the fact that $P(\{H\}) = p$?

**Clarifications**

The definition of a random variable given in the book:

> A *random variable* is a function from a sample space $S$ into the real numbers.

The definition of $P_X$ given in the book:

> Suppose we have a sample space
>
> $S = \{s_1,...,s_n \}$
>
> with a probability function $P$ and we define a random variable $X$
> with range $\chi = \{x_1,...,x_m\}$. We can define a probability
> function $P_x$ on $\chi$ in the following way. We will observe $X =
>  x_i$ if and only if the outcome of the random experiment is an $s_j
>  \in S$ such that $X(s_j) = x_i$. Thus,
>
> $(1.4.1) \quad P_X(X = x_i) = P(\{s_j \in S : X(s_j) = x_i \}).$
>
> Note that the left-hand side of (1.4.1), the function $P_X$ is an
> *induced* probability function on $\chi$, defined in terms of the original function $P$. Equation (1.4.1) formally defines a probability
> function, $P_X$, for the random variable $X$. Of course, we have to
> verify that $P_X$ satisfies the Kolmogorov Axioms, but htat is not a
> very difficult job (see Excercise 1.45). **Because of the equivalence
> in (1.4.1), we will simply write $P(X = x_i)$ rather than $P_X(X =
>  x_i)$**
>
> A *note on notation:* Random variables will always be denoted with
> uppercase letters and the realized values of the variable (or its
> range) will be denoted by the corresponding lowercase letters. Thus,
> the random variable $X$ can take the value $x$.

Definition of cummulative distribution function of a random variable given in the book:

> The cummulative distribution function or cdf of a random variable $X$,
> denoted by $F_X(x)$, is defined by   $F_X(x) = P_X(X \leq x), \quad $
> for all $x$.

Up until the example in question, density and mass functions have not been covered. The notation $P(X = x)$ has also not been explained to have any different meaning than in their remark in the definition of $P_X$. Previously to defining random variables, they have only used notation like $P(A)$ for a set (event) $A$ or more informal notation like $P(\text{the sum is } 8)$ . Therefore, because of the remark they made in the definition of $P_X$, I assumed they use $P_X(X=x)$ and $P(X=x)$ interchangeably. They have used the notation $P_X(X = 27)$, $P_X(X = i)$, $P(X \leq 2.5)$ and $P(X = 0, 1, \text{or} 2)$ in examples just before the example of my question.

Comment: Are you sure that the authors write $P$ for $P_X$? I have severe doubts about that. Your notation $P_X(X=x)$ sows confusion. The random variable on probability space $(S,B,P)$ induces a new probability measure, but this time on ($\mathbb N,\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$). This probability measure is usually denoted as $P_X$ and carries the name "distribution of $X$". So this $P_X$ exists *by the grace of* $P$ and $X$. It is defined by $P_X(A):=P(\{X\in A\})$ for every $x\in\mathbb N$. The function prescribed by $x\mapsto P_X(\{x\})$ is then the so-called probability mass function of $X$.

Comment: In short: "$P_X(X=x)$" is not a meaningful expression if $P_X$ is defined as in my former comment. Meaningful expressions are $P(\{X=x\})$ often abbreviated by $P(X=x)$, and $P_X(\{x\})$ sometimes abbreviated as $P_X(x)$. This under the equality $P_X(x)=P(X=x)$. For good understanding consistency in notation is important here. That's why I make these remarks.

Comment: @drhab Does a subscript make a difference? That is $P_X(X = x)$ vs. $P_X(X = x_i)$? I have edited my question with some clarifications on notation and definitions given in the book. They certainly use notation like $P_X(X = x_i)$, $P_X(X=27)$, $P_X(X = i)$ etc...

Comment: In principle a subscript makes no difference but should only be used if it serves a real goal and makes things more clear.Starting with probability space $(S,B,P)$ why on earth should we suddenly write $P_X$ for $P$?..Also you rob yourself from a nice way to denote the probability measure that is induced by $X$. This probability measure (mentioned in my comment) is one that is strictly connected with $X$. This in contrast with the $P$ in $(S,B,P)$. We can define more random variables $Y,Z$ et cetera on the space. Should we go for $P=P_X=P_Y=P_Z$ then? I only see disadvantages.

Comment: "But formally I think we ought to give the definition of $P_X$ in terms of $P$?...." How to do that if $P$ and $P_X$ denote the same probability measure? Then we already have $P=P_X$ haven't we? So what more could be said? Especially the practicized notation makes it hard for me to see what your problem really is.

Comment: "How to do that if P and PX denote the same probability measure? ", well that's a good point, I guess I am confusing notation with actual functions. Let me rephrase myself, I think the issue I have is this: I feel like the formula for $P_X(X=x)=(1-p)^{x-1}p$ should relate to the events in the sample space. $p$ relates to the sample space because $P(\{H\})=p$, but I don't see how the factor $(1-p)$ relates to an event in $S$, because $\{T\}$ is not an event in $S$. I think it is weird to define $P$ in terms of an event that does not exist in the sample space. Does that make sense?

Comment: I only have a very basic understanding of probability theory, so I am not familiar with terms like "probability space" and "probability measure", but I will read up on it. Thanks for your comments.